# Реализация shrink_to_fit для множества векторов

Tags: c++

Есть шаблон класса, хранящий множество векторов:

```
template <class T>
class Lots {
    std::set<std::vector<T>> sv;
public:     
    //есть функции, выполняющие различные действия с элементами sv  
    //в том числе и вставка/удаление    
};
```

Может быть, что  обьект  `sv`  вполне может хранить вектора, занимающие память с запасом, например такие(специально грубый пример):

```
    vector<int> v1, v2, v3;
    v1.reserve(10);
    v2.reserve(v1.capacity() * 3);
    v3.reserve(2 * v2.capacity());
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    m = n % 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        v1.push_back(i + 1);
        v2.push_back(i + 2);
        v3.push_back(i + 3);
    }
```

где неизвестно, какой обьем займут данные.
По этой причине я решил добавить в класс метод  `shrink_to_fit` и реализовать следующим образом:

```
template <class T>
void Lots<T>::shrink_to_fit() {
    auto It = sv.begin();
    for (auto v : sv) {
        v.shrink_to_fit();
        sv.insert(It++, v);
    }
}
```

Но тут есть недостаток:  копируются все вектора и при  чтении и  при записи.

1. Как реализовать ее лучше?
2. Возможно ли сжать вектора  не полностью, а, скажем, с запасом на 2    элемента?
   P.S. Учитывая содержание комментариев... если я не очень ясно выразился,  прошу простить и стараться понять суть вопроса

Comment: Что-то очень смущает `for (auto v : sv) {
        v.shrink_to_fit();` с последующей вставкой... Т.е. вы копируете (кстати, думаю (но не уверен), что при копировании вы и так получите в векторе места ровно необходимое количество) вектор опять во множество? А зачем? Нужны ли вам лишние вектора?... Да и потом - [*It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled.*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) - так что он в полном праве ничего не делать...

Comment: @Harry, вот  поэтому и возник вопрос, поскольку я хочу заменить вектора  сжатым вариантом этих же векторов, но моя реализация мне не понравилась. И мне эта ссылька не нужна, это я знаю. Вопрос в другом

Comment: @vegorov , это ошибка, это попытка урезать размер элементов

Comment: @vegorov, Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E1086 the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::shrink_to_fit [with _Ty=int, _Alloc=std::allocator<int>]"  И о каких сравнениях векторов речь, я не понел.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan о том, которые выполняет std::set когда ищет элементы внутри себя. Это же дерево. Но это уже не важно, std::set не позволяет модицировать элементы, которые содержит. Я как-то забыл оО `Because both iterator and const_iterator are constant iterators (and may in fact be the same type), it is not possible to mutate the elements of the container through an iterator returned by any of these member functions. ` [std::set::begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Так что копировать, редактировать, удалять оригинальный и вставлять отредактированный вам всё равно придётся. с std::set, по крайней мере.

Comment: @vegorov, да, но я подумал, а вдруг есть другое решение

Comment: Возьмите std::unordered_map<hash, std::vector<T>>, так получится. Только Хэши от векторов считать понадобится, и обновлять в случае чего.

Answer (score 1):

При желании можно что-то придумать, но это не очень правильно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
class MyVector{
public:
    MyVector() = default;
    MyVector(const std::initializer_list<T>& l):
        m_v{l}
    {}
    MyVector(const MyVector&) = default;
    MyVector& operator=(const MyVector&) = default;
    virtual ~MyVector() = default;

    void shrink_to_fit() const{
        m_v.shrink_to_fit();
    }

    bool operator<(const MyVector& other) const{
        return m_v < other.m_v;
    }

    std::vector<T>& value() const{
        return m_v;
    }

private:
    mutable std::vector<T> m_v;
};

int main()
{
    std::set<MyVector<int>> sv{
        {1,2,3,5},
        {3,4,5}
    };
    for (auto& v: sv){
        v.value().reserve(100);
        std::cout << v.value().capacity() << std::endl;
    }
    for (auto& v: sv){
        v.shrink_to_fit();
        std::cout << v.value().capacity() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, есть такая логика работать с другим типом. А может получится просто написать компаратор для set?...

Comment: Так а при чём тут компаратор? Исходная проблема в том, что чтобы выполнить `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` по месту в контейнере, нужно чтобы был доступ к элементу по ссылке, а не по константной ссылке. std::set такой функционал не предоставляет. Вы можете вставить, удалить, проверить наличие, найти. Соответственно, либо менять контейнер, либо писать кастомный тип обёртку над `std::vector`, позволяющий выполнять некоторые неконстантные методы по константной ссылке.Но только те методы, которые не поменяют инвариант сравнения двух элементов в std::set.std::shrink_to_fit или std::reserve, например

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, просто держите указатели на вектор в `set` с кастомным компараторм

Comment: @vegorov, да, верно...

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb,  спасибо, попробую